# Scalable why not scaling software levels

Tags: kubernetes, scalability

In software development, the scalability goal is to add `hardware resources` to increase processing power.

However, in the case of microservices, extending a service, such as `multiple POD replicas in Kubernetes`, can also improve processing power.

Personally, I think this should be a `software` upgrade, not a hardware one.

How do you explain this question? Thank you very much

Comment: This is a highly opinion-based question which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow in general. Try asking in your local community or on websites like Twitter.

Comment: But as a general answer: not all systems can be scaled horizontally, and some that can pay a substantial price in terms of drawbacks if you do so. For example databases, single-primary systems like Postgres have a lot of advantages over distributed databases in both simplicity and ACID characteristics.